# iOS Dropbox Core API Expired Access Token

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was getting Error Code 401, and it seems like my access token has expired. Dropbox reference says the following:
"Access tokens may be disabled by the user (from the account page), revoked by Dropbox administrators in cases of abuse, or simply expire over time."

I have not disabled anything and I used to have proper access and upload files without any problem, so I assume the access token has expired. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Dropbox SDK - Cannot upload or get metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325875/ios-dropbox-sdk-cannot-upload-or-get-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs) you need to re-authenticate the user:

```
401 Bad or expired token. This can happen if the user or Dropbox revoked or expired an access token. To fix, you should re-authenticate the user.
```

Comment: I just saw that as well... does that mean I have to disable the app on the console and enable it again? Or is it something that's done in my code?

Comment: Is re-authentication done in my code or in the Dropbox console? Because I created a new project on the console, used this new App Key and Secret, but same result, which makes me suppose it's something on my code, but I cannot figure out what...

Comment: In your code, you need to re-authenticate the user with OAuth.

Comment: `[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];`    This is what I've tried in order to unlink the session so it can authenticate once again, but still not working.